# Streamlit -Aggrid date filter - unable to filter

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I am not sure why, but I am unable to filter the date.

When I filter its either blank or it doesn't filter at all
[before filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYthf.png), [after filter using greater than](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2a93.png), [after filter using the equals to filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExtoI.png)
Below is my code:

```
st.markdown(hide_menu,unsafe_allow_html=True)
file_upload = st.file_uploader('Upload file','.xlsx')

if file_upload is not None:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_upload)
    #st.checkbox("Use container width", value=False, key="use_container_width")

    #Installation Duration
    df['Installation_Actual_End'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Installation_Actual_End"])
    df['Installation_Actual_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Installation_Actual_Start"])
    df['Installation_Duration'] = df["Installation_Actual_End"] - df["Installation_Actual_Start"]
    df["Installation_Duration"] = df["Installation_Duration"]
       
    df1 = df['Installation_Actual_Start','Installation_Actual_End','Integration']
    
    
    AgGrid(df1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a format parameter in the conversion to datetime see code below.

## Code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid


file_upload = st.file_uploader('Upload file','.xlsx')

if file_upload is not None:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_upload)

    st.write('### Initial data')
    st.dataframe(df)

    # Add format parameter based from excel data format.
    df['Installation_Actual_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Installation_Actual_Start'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    df['Installation_Actual_End'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Installation_Actual_End"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    df['Installation_Duration_Hr'] = (df["Installation_Actual_End"] - df["Installation_Actual_Start"]).astype('timedelta64[h]')

    st.write('### Date conversion')
    st.dataframe(df)

    # Select column to show.
    df1 = df[['Installation_Actual_Start', 'Installation_Actual_End', 'Integration']]

    st.write('### AgGrid')
    AgGrid(df1)
```

## Output

[image]

## Excel

[image]

Comment: I tested out but did not get the same output, I've added the output to the answer. Kindly please advise.

Comment: Try to create an excel with same entries as mine.

Comment: If it works on my sample data and not work on your excel file, the problem could be on your excel file. Perhaps check the date formatting of your excel file.

Comment: Hi @ferdy , i tried creating exactly like yours but the filter isnt working for me. May I know what format you use on your excel for the dates ?

Comment: Custom format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: many thanks for your help, after reinstallation of streamlit. I am able to filter and get the output.

Answer (score 0):

[test_image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcfDX.png)
[test_image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6dMh.png)

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid


file_upload = st.file_uploader('Upload file','.xlsx')

if file_upload is not None:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_upload)

    st.write('### Initial data')
    st.dataframe(df)

    # Add format parameter based from excel data format.
    df['Installation_Actual_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Installation_Actual_Start'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    df['Installation_Actual_End'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Installation_Actual_End"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    df['Installation_Duration_Hr'] = (df["Installation_Actual_End"] - df["Installation_Actual_Start"]).astype('timedelta64[h]')

    st.write('### Date conversion')
    st.dataframe(df)

    # Select column to show.
    df1 = df[['Installation_Actual_Start', 'Installation_Actual_End']]

    st.write('### AgGrid')
    AgGrid(df1)
```

Hi @ferdy,
Thank you for taking you time to answer my doubts.
I tested the code, but it wasn't working in my end. in the agrid columns it seems the data did not appear full as your screenshot. I've attached the output that im getting.